# Property does not exist on type using typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor

App.ts

```
import { $, WebElement } from 'protractor';
export class App {

  public appName: WebElement;

  constructor() {
    this.appName = $('#appName');
  }
}
```

app.e2e.test.ts

```
import { browser, $ } from 'protractor';
import { App } from '../pageobjects/App'
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:1344';

describe('App', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get(BASE_URL);
  });

  it('should load the Sites UI homepage', () => {
    console.log(App.appName);
  });
});
```

Any idea why I cannot access the properties defined in `App.ts`?

Error:

```
> tsc -p tsconfig.test.json && protractor dist/protractor.config.js

test/e2e/app.e2e.test.ts(15,28): error TS2339: Property 'appName' does not exist on type 'typeof App'.
```

Comment: you are trying to access it on the typeof App, not on an instance of the class. You need to create an instance of that class before accessing properties. Maybe some reading on the difference between class and class instance would help. :) https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-an-object-a-class-and-an-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your exception its pretty clear what's wrong:

```
property 'appName' does not exist on type 'typeof App'.
```

for this to work you need the declare a new instance of `App` like so:

```
describe('App', () => {
  app: App;

  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get(BASE_URL);
    app = new App();
  });

  it('should load the Sites UI homepage', () => {
    console.log(app.appName);
  });
});
```